# A night out at Luigi's

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Hi Puzzling SE at the moment I am at a romantic night out in a fancy restaurant. Tonight the owner, Luigi, who is also a riddle fanatic has decided to put a little riddle on the menu. It was stated that whoever could solve it would get whatever free 3 course meal and bottle of wine for himself/herself and the partner. I really want to impress my wife tonight and I have roughly an hour here to solve the riddle before we finish our meals and pay the bills. Can you help?

Riddle:

"VVV!", said a M called C when C L on a C with a flag with a X that was not D.

Who is it?

Comment: Ok, here are my workings so far. It might have something to do with roman Numerals.

V=5
M=5000
C=100
L=50
X=10
D=500

Comment: Who keeps downvoting this????

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker you cannot "keep downvoting" you can only downvote any particular question / answer once. If you are receiving multiple downvotes it most likely means that several people decided independently that your question deserves a downvote

Comment: Could be one person on multiple accounts...

Comment: I have had 5 upvotes... to the downvoters please show yourself and explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve Luigi's riddle we must:

> Replace each Roman numeral in the sentence with a word beginning with the same letter, or - in the case of X - resembling its shape.

If we do this as Luigi intends, we will end up with:

> A phrase revolving around a famous event from Roman military history (appropriately enough, since Luigi and his restaurant are (presumably) Italian, and Rome is the capital city of Italy).

It works out as:

> "**VENI VIDI VICI**!", said a **MAN** called **CAESAR** when **CAESAR LANDED** on a **COUNTRY** with a flag with a **CROSS** that was not **DENMARK**.

Doubtless, Luigi intends this as a reference to:

> **Julius Caesar's conquest of England** (a nation whose flag is a red *cross* on a white background) - the event which *[Veni, Vidi, Vici](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici)* ("I came, I saw, I conquered") is commonly misremembered as bring connected to. It should be noted, however, that this quote of Caesar's actually refers to the outcome of the [Battle of Zela](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Zela) in Zile in modern-day Turkey!

Now enjoy your free meal and wine and please come back to Luigi's again! *Buona notte!*

Comment: Yeah I knew that by the way but it would not make a good riddle otherwise!

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Not a criticism of your puzzle! More intended as a remark about Luigi's misconception being a common one - will make that clearer with an edit when I can :)

Comment: Also just in the nick of time!!!